# Exit code from powershell script when terminating from subfunction

Tags: function, powershell, exit

I have a Powershell script running which calls a function from a dot-sourced .ps1 file.
Inside this function I do an `exit 1` which terminates the whole script (as intended).
When I now look at `$?` and `$LASTEXITCODE` it says `True` and `0`.
Shouldn't there be `False` and `1`?
Is there anything I don't see?

Example:
main script:

```
Log-Error -Error "some error" -exit $True
```

in function.ps1:

```
Function Log-Finish {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][boolean]$Exit)
    Process {
        " error "
        # If $Exit is $true, end calling script
        If(($Exit) -or ($Exit -eq $True)) {
            Exit 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code. I try, what you describe, and get `False` and `1` in the result.

Comment: added to original post

Comment: Please include code calling main script and checking of `$?` and `$LASTEXITCODE`. And in function.ps1 you have `Log-Finish`, but in main script you calling `Log-Error`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed answer.
In function1.ps1, log-error calls log-finish if parameter -exit is $true. 
i check $? and $lastexitcode manually in the PS console after running the main script. As far as I understand, if I call Log-Error in the main script (which calls Log-Finish in the functions.ps1) the main script should abort with $? False / $lastexitcode 1, right?

Comment: Yes, it should. And for me, it does.

Comment: Pretty strange. I just tested it again. The output from Log-Finish is written (" error "), but $? shows True. I think I'm missing something here...

Comment: Well... It works, wonder why... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You will found an explanation to your "issue" in this post http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/12/powershell-error-handling-and-why-you-should-care.aspx

> Also, remember that when external command or script is run, $? will
>   not always tell you a true story. Let’s see why. Create a script that
>   has nothing but one line—our favorite error generating command:
>
> Get-Item afilethatdoesntexist.txt
>
> Now run the script and see the output. You will notice that the host
>   shows you the error. You will also notice that $error contains the
>   error object that was generated by the command in the script. But $?
>   Is set to TRUE! Oh, and don’t try this in the order I mentioned
>   because it will skew the results of $?.
>
> So can you tell me why $? Is set to True? Because your script ran
>   successfully as far as Windows PowerShell is concerned. Every step in
>   script was executed—whether it resulted in an error or not. And that
>   was successful in doing what the script told Windows PowerShell to do.
>   It doesn’t necessarily mean that the commands within script didn’t
>   generate any error. See how quickly it gets confusing? And we haven’t
>   started to go deep yet!